# Minimum and Maximum of an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to sort an array of numbers, so that it returns its minumum and its maximum. The code I've written so far doesn't seem to do anything at all.

```
function sort(array) {
    arrayNew = [];
    maximum = array[0];
    minimum = array[0];

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (maximum < array[i]) {
            maximum = array[i];
        }
    }
    arrayNew.push(maximum);

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (minimum > array[i]) {
            minimum = array[i];
        }
    }
    arrayNew.unshift(minumum);
    return arrayNew;
}


var arr1 = [3, 8, 7, 6, 5, -4, 3, 2, 1];
alert(sort(arr1));
```

Comment: You have a misspelling: `arrayNew.unshift(minumum);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `minumum` is spelled incorrectly. It should have been `minimum`
2. Don't use your variables without declaring them with `var` keyword. Otherwise they will become global properties.
3. Also, you can have your minimum check also in the same loop as `maximum`. So, your code can be shortened like this

   ```
   function sort(array) {
       var maximum = array[0],
           minimum = array[0],
           i;

       for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
           if (maximum < array[i]) {
               maximum = array[i];
           }

           if (minimum > array[i]) {
               minimum = array[i];
           }
       }
       return [minimum, maximum];
   }
   ```
4. Now that we know, we can do it like this, lets try to shorten it more with ternary operator

   ```
   function sort(array) {
       var maximum = array[0],
           minimum = array[0],
           i;

       for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
           maximum = maximum < array[i] ? array[i] : maximum;
           minimum = minimum > array[i] ? array[i] : minimum;
       }
       return [minimum, maximum];
   }
   ```

Comment: Not `for (var i = 0`? particularly given your second point? @thefourtheye?

Answer (score 2):

In case you didn't know there is a much simpler way to get the min and max values from an array - use `Math.min` and `Math.min` with `apply`:

```
var min = Math.min.apply(null, arr1);
var max = Math.max.apply(null, arr1);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4k5mjjdx/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I knew about the Math object, I was just trying this as a "side" exercise of one I was assigned

Comment: Even I thought about this, but then I decided to go with the looping. Because, it finds the max and min in single iteration.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [ 3, 8, 7, 6, 5, -4, 31, 2, 21, 20, 1 ].sort(function(a, b) { return a - b }),  // [-4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 20, 21, 31]
    min = arr[0],  // min
    max = arr[arr.length-1];  //max
```

Comment: javascript's default sort is lexiographic not numerical, that function won't work for numbers above 10. Yes the OP used the same array but they never said they are limited to this set. Best to correct it for posterity.

Comment: Updated the sort method with a sort function.

Answer (score 0):

`arrayNew.unshift(minumum);` is wrong variable `minimum`

correct one : `arrayNew.unshift(minimum);`

Comment: Please double-check your answer. It does not make any sense.

Comment: I checked my answer and he is using wrong variable. minumum does not exists.